# Keep project parts in one repository or split into multiple

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

**TL;DR** Should all parts of midish sized project be in one repository or should each part have own repo?

I'm starting new project in C++ (but I think this is language agnostic), which will consist of few parts. Server, Client - linux (while clients can also work p2p), Client - android, ...

I'll probably support linux, windows and android for clients, server linux only.

I'm thinking it'll be midish size project. Having multiple versions released at once is not important to me, current (and only maintained) version will be trunk. I'll use feature&bug branches though.

And now finally to my question. Should I just use one repo for all of this? I can imagine it simplifying things a little bit. And I'm not starting Kernel 2.0, there won't be that many files (I hope).

Development environment will be vim & bash & cmake if that's relevant

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest each part should have its own repo.

The reasons are client and server have very different release cycle. At the very beginning when the communication protocol is not stabilized both change in more or less the same pace, and the change to make on them are high correlated.

However things will be changed when the protocol stabilized. The development of client and server become quite independent and they will have their own objective. For example, you plan to improve the UI of the client , but doing small code change for performance on server. So you may have many quick commits and frequent release on server, but it does not affect the development of the client. An independent git graph on each part gives a clear view to you.

For the clients of different platform, it is very subjective. If consistency in UI, functionality and performance among different clients is a main objective, then I would suggest one repo for all client-platform. Otherwise, each platform can have it's own repo.

In fact as you also know, there is no right or wrong. In my opinion, the key factor is the correlation among parts and whether they have similar/synchronized release cycles.

Comment: hm, the fact that client and server development pace will drift apart with time didn't occur to me at all.. you are likely right. I've to think about clients (one vs multi repo), but you have a point that client and server would probably be better separate. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

For *any* size of project using multi-part or single-part pattern is more question of

- the maintainability
- the separation and allocation of responsibilities, rights and powers

than the size of project

In your (rather complex) structure multi-repository (subtree-based) structure seems as logical and reasonable decision